# javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval<>Z

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, junit

I've searched everywhere but I didn't found a good answer.
I am developping a maven application using Hibernate + Spring + Mysql.
Here is my application-context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http:...">

<bean id='dataSource' class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/university"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="admin"/>
</bean>

<bean id='sessionFactory' class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.university.entities.Course</value>
            <value>com.university.entities.Student</value>
            <value>com.university.entities.Teacher</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id='transactionManager' class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref='sessionFactory'/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.university.dao"></context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

and Here is my pom.xml :

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.6.7.Final</hibernate.version>
    <jsf.version>2.2.4</jsf.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.1</slf4j.version>
    <primefaces.version>4.0</primefaces.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>

    <!-- Tests unitaires avec junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- antlr -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Package entities -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-rev-1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mysql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.16</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But when I try to test a simple DAO as :

```
package com.university.dao.test;
import java.util.List;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import com.university.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.university.entities.Student;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:application-context.xml" })

public class StudentDAOTest extends TestCase {

private static Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(StudentDAOTest.class);

@Autowired
private StudentDAO studentDAO;

@Test
public void testFindAll() {
    List<Student> listStudent = studentDAO.findAll();
    LOG.debug(listStudent);
    assertNotNull(listStudent);
}

@Test
public void testCreateOrUpdate() {
    Student newStudent = new Student("Abderrahmen ISSA", "07701607");
    studentDAO.createOrUpdate(newStudent);
    assertNotNull(newStudent.getId());
}

@Test
public void testFindById() {
    Integer id = 2;
    Student student = studentDAO.findById(id);
    assertNotNull(student);
}

@Test
public void testRemove() {
    Student userToRemove = new Student("User To Test Remove", "11111111");
    studentDAO.createOrUpdate(userToRemove);
    Integer id = userToRemove.getId();

    studentDAO.remove(userToRemove);
    Student student = studentDAO.findById(id);
    assertNull(student);
    }

}
```

The Student class is :

```
package com.university.entities;
// Generated 20 oct. 2013 20:53:03 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
/**
 * Student generated by hbm2java
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "student", catalog = "university")
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String mail;
private Date birthDate;
private String birthPlace;
private String cin;
private Integer mobile;
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>(0);

public Student() {
}

public Student(String mail, String cin) {
    this.mail = mail;
    this.cin = cin;
}

public Student(String name, String mail, Date birthDate, String birthPlace,
        String cin, Integer mobile, Set<Course> courses) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mail = mail;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
    this.cin = cin;
    this.mobile = mobile;
    this.courses = courses;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "name", length = 45)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "mail", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getMail() {
    return this.mail;
}

public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "birthDate", length = 10)
public Date getBirthDate() {
    return this.birthDate;
}

public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

@Column(name = "birthPlace", length = 45)
public String getBirthPlace() {
    return this.birthPlace;
}

public void setBirthPlace(String birthPlace) {
    this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
}

@Column(name = "cin", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getCin() {
    return this.cin;
}

public void setCin(String cin) {
    this.cin = cin;
}

@Column(name = "mobile")
public Integer getMobile() {
    return this.mobile;
}

public void setMobile(Integer mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "course_has_student", catalog = "university", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Student_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Course_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Course> getCourses() {
    return this.courses;
}

public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [name=" + name + ", mail=" + mail + ", cin=" + cin
            + "]";
}
}
```

The StudentDAOImpl :

```
package com.university.dao.impl;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.university.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.university.entities.Student;

@Repository("studentDAO")
public class StudentDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Student> implements
    StudentDAO {
}
```

The GenericDAOImpl :

```
package com.university.dao.impl;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.university.dao.GenericDAO;

@Transactional
public abstract class GenericDAOImpl<T> implements GenericDAO<T> {

@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

/**
 * Unit.
 */
private final Class<T> entityBeanType;

/**
 * Instantiates a new GenericServiceImpl.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public GenericDAOImpl() {
    this.entityBeanType = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

protected final Session getCurrentSession() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Session Factory has not been set on DAO before usage");
    }
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

/**
 * Gets the entity bean type.
 * 
 * @return the entity bean type
 */
public final Class<T> getEntityBeanType() {
    return entityBeanType;
}

public void createOrUpdate(T entity) {
    getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<T> findAll() {
    return getCurrentSession().createQuery(
            "from " + getEntityBeanType().getName()).list();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T findById(Integer id) {
    T entity = (T) getCurrentSession().get(getEntityBeanType(), id);
    return entity;
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
}
}
```

I can run the DAOTest on eclipse well but with mvn test I get :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationEception : Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [application-context.xml] : Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError :
>   javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval<>Z.

Help please !

Comment: Can you share Student class, especially annotations?

Answer (score 1):

You have a library conflict. Have you set this up as Hibernate project in Eclipse so that Eclipse added necessary JARs to the classpath? This would explain why it works in Eclipse but not in the Maven build.

Anyway, ensure the Hibernate library versions match e.g 4.1.8.Final and remove the javax.persistence-api dependency.

This all you should need in your POM regarding Hibernate. Everything else will be resolved transitively by Maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In Java build path I have hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar, When I remove this jar, I get the same error :
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z

Comment: Well as I say you have a library conflict. Make the changes I have suggested in the POM and see if the Maven build works. If so remove any manually added JARs in the Eclipse project and let Maven manage your Eclipse project libraries via the M2e plugin.

Comment: I have to change <bean id='sessionFactory' class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> to
 <bean id='sessionFactory' class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> ?

Comment: Should I use all of theses ?
hibernate-core 4.1.8.Final
hibernate-entitymanager 4.1.8.Final
hibernate-commons-annotations 3.2.0.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api 1.0.0.Final

Comment: You only need the two dependencies I have specified. Remove the javax-persistence dependency you have specified and all hibernate dependecies other than these 2. Regarding the entityManager, can you add your DAO class to our question.

Comment: Okay, a more up-to-date mechanism is to to code against the JPA specification rather than the Hibernate specific classes. So rather than sessionFactory and session you are working with an EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager. See here for a complete example: http://java.dzone.com/articles/persistence-layer-spring-31-0 Although you should be bale to get your existing code running by updating the sessionFactory class as you suggested.